# How to remove black photos from Gallery. [Android/Xamarin]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gallery, photos

1. I want to delete photos from gallery but after deletion i still have files - black frames there:
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYw6L.png)
2. I tried:

   File fdelete = new File(ImageFile._dir.AbsolutePath + "/img.jpg");
   if (fdelete.Exists())
   {
       if (fdelete.Delete())
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Deleted.");
           }
   }
3. `ImageFile._dir.AbsolutePath` returns: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Gifs`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you need to use the MediaStore API, not just delete files from the disk

Comment: Thanks :) I used this helper: https://gist.github.com/wislon/9fabd1cf250bbf96062a#file-mediagalleryhelper-cs